# How can I write xbox controller inputs over a usb with raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, xbox, xinput

I can only seem to find information regarding reading xinputs from an xbox original/360/one controller, but is there a way to WRITE inputs over a usb connection? Want to be able to read input from and xbox controller or regular controller, and send those inputs (translated to the opposite, or between different xbox versions) over a usb-a to usb-a connection with a console. I'd like to be able to do this with python on a raspberry pi (with xboxdrv if possible), but I can use different libraries or possibly different languages if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulate a Gaming Device - Raspberry PI Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139136/emulate-a-gaming-device-raspberry-pi-zero)

Comment: @Woodford no, but I figured out how to use an arduino to do it and connect the pi to that with the GPIO ports